# How to get added entity Id? Entity Framework 6 Oracle 11

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-6, identity

I am using EF6 database first, against Oracle 11. the tables ids are generated by trigger using a sequence in the database.

When I add an entity through EF, the ID is not retrieved back as expected, any clue what is wrong?

```
using (var Context = new Context())
{
    Context.DATASETS.Add(datasetToAdd);
    Context.SaveChanges();
}
```

`datasetToAdd.ID` is not populated.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the database column is `IDENTITY`, and that `StoreGeneratedPattern` is set to `Identity` in EDMX.

Comment: Oracle 11 does not have Identity columns, the ID is a primary key generated by trigger on insert, and the ID values comes from a sequence.